# How I can see the Top location of a screen in a FragmentLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I set my FrameLayout as a parent view and set an attribute scrolling behavior. After scrolling downwards If the user triggers the OnBackPress
the screen should go to the top most part of that view. How can I do this?

```
<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <--ChildViews--->
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to use content_frame.scrollTo(0,0); but its now working.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your FrameLayout into a ScrollView firstly, instead of call content_frame.scrollTo(0,0), try ScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0)

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      >

    <!--ChildViews -->
  </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

**and I noticed** that you may use CoordinatorLayout as your root view, if in that case, you better use android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView, cause NestedScrollView will delegate the touch event to a NestedScrollingParent firstly if present.

Comment: Yes you are correct already solved it yesterday using ScrollView.scrollTo(0.0)

Comment: I already did what you said the problem now,  if I use NestedScrollView
the RecycleView doesn't listen the OnScrolledLister when I include in the FrameLayout.